# Angular and checkbox validation

Tags: angular, angular-validation

I have a problem with validation. Can someone help me with validation for this four checkboxes? I need custom function that returns error when all `checkbox.checked` are `false`. How to solve it?

form.component.html:

```
<div class="form-group" formControlName="levels">
    <label>LEVELS</label>
    <div *ngFor="let data of levels">
        <input 
          type="checkbox" 
          [checked]="data.checked" 
        > {{data.level}}
    </div>
</div>
```

form.component.ts:

```
constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

    this.levels = [ 
        { level: "Szkoła podstawowa", checked: false }, 
        { level: "Gimnazjum", checked: false }, 
        { level: "Liceum", checked: false }, 
        { level: "Studia", checked: false } 
    ];

    this.offerForm = this._formBuilder.group({ 
        levels: null
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should create a `FormArray` from your level array. Use this FormArray in the formBuilder and add a custom validator that checks if at least one item is true (I think there's no default validator for this). You can find information about how to use [FormArrays](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray) and how to write [custom validators](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators) in the official documentation.

Comment: Given the keywords from my answer you should be able to find lots of examples online. Maybe not for the very specific case but if you know what FormArrays are and how to write a custom validator combining these two is no hard task.

Comment: But how to insert that four inputs from *ngFor into array?